# Python opposite of eval()

Tags: python, functional-programming, eval

Is it possible to do the opposite of `eval()` in python which treats inputs as literal strings? For example `f(Node(2)) -> 'Node(2)'` or if there's some kind of higher-order operator that stops interpreting the input like lisp's `quote()` operator.

Comment: Can you please provide additional details, such as what exactly you are doing in Python, what kind of input are you passing, because as it is we can't possibly tell if you are confusing between `input` and `raw_input` (as in Python 2), or confusion between [`eval` vs `ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval).

Comment: No, there isn't. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here anyway?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm doing an n-ary tree traversal. While I understand the common way to do it, it came to me that the literal input might be the solution(e.g. `Node(1, [Node(3, [Node(5), Node(6)]), Node(2), Node(4)])` -> [1,3,5,6,2,4])

Comment: @ShukaiNi I think this is a fine and answerable question in principle, and people not familiar with LISP might just not appreciate what quotation does. But you are confusing a couple of things, and the use case you mentions seems to be rather an X-Y-problem.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to **does Python have `quote`** is no, Python does not have `quote`.  There's no homoiconicity, and no native infrastructure to represent the languages own source code.

Now for **what is the opposite of `eval`**: you seem to be missing some part the picture here.  Python's `eval` is not the opposite of `quote`.  There's three types values can be represented as: as unparsed strings, as expressions, and as values (of any type).

- `quote` and LISP-style "`eval`" convert between expressions and values.
- Parsing and pretty printing form another pair between expressions and strings.
- Python's actual `eval` goes directly from strings to values, and `repr` goes back (in the sense of printing a parsable value<sup>1</sup>).

Since SO does not support drawing diagrams:

[image]

So if you are looking for the opposite of `eval`, it's either trivially `repr`, but that might not really help you, or it would be the composition of `quote` and pretty priniting, if there were quoting in Python.

This composition with string functions a bit cumbersome, which is why LISPs let the reader deal with parsing once and for all, and from that point on only go between expressions and values.  I don't know any language that has such a "quote + print" function, actually (C#'s [`nameof`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/nameof) comes close, but is restricted to names).

Some caveats about the diagram:

1. It does not commute: you have deal with pure values or disregard side effects, for one, and most importantly `quote` is not really a function in some sense, of course.  It's a [special form](https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_3.html).  That's why `repr(x)` is not the same as `prettyprint(quote(x))`, in general.
2. It's not depicting pairs of isomorphisms.  Multiple expressions can `eval` to the same value etc.

<sup>1</sup>That's not always the case in reality, but that's what it's suppsedly there for.

Comment: Thanks, the diagram helps a lot in clarifying the internal representations.